# How can I get started with migrating my winforms application to ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to convert my winform VB.NET application to an ASP.NET application.
My current application has 4 forms, it reads a remote XML file, and uses a `datagrid` to collect user input and to create a report.
It is a very simple application, and I would like to know where to start to convert it to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fairly straightforward to port the functionality.

You should start by checking out the tutorials at the [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/learn/) website.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as start a new web project and create the current forms as WinForms.  There is no magic tool that I am aware of that does this conversion.

You'll need a server to host the web application on as well.

Unless I am missing something, sounds very simple.

Comment: er, that would be WebForms for a browser-based solution, no?

Comment: Definitely a typo. WebForms is what he meant.

Comment: typo...sorry.  I meant WebForms :)

Answer (score 1):

It won't take very much by all accounts.

No one is going to be able to give you a "just do this" solution to your problem.

What you need to do is work through a couple of simple Web Forms examples and you'll soon see the similarities and be able to migrate the code.

Comment: can you recommend some web form examples?

Comment: hey greg can u recommend some nice examples?